# Unable to Filter Proper Data from DataGridView Based on DocDate

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I've following SQL Query which fills data in my datagridview

```
Select Code,Name,FromDate,ToDate From Contacts
```

[image: SQL Query Result]

Below is the RowFilter Query which i am using to filter data, but it filters incorrect data.
FromDate and ToDate are DateTime Columnns

```
(FromDate <= @DocDateTime AND ToDate >= @DocDateTime)
```

IF My @DocDateTime is '2014-05-07 12:04:22.610'
Then result should come as

[image: Filtered Data]

Comment: Can you explain more? What result you get? Are you getting rows having dates beyond this specified range in where clause?

Comment: @HassanNisar I have added images in question for better understanding

Comment: Are you providing string values in command parameters?

Comment: @HassanNisar I am using Datagridview.RowFilter = My filter query. I didn't understand your above comment

Comment: You are applying RowFilter on data source binded with datagridview? It must be `DataSet` or `DataTable`?

Comment: yes its a dataset containing datatable in it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52175/discussion-between-hassan-nisar-and-prakash-vishwakarma)